# constexpr constructor must initialize direct base class (Visual Studio)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++20

I have someone else's code that I shouldn't alter:

```
struct Parent { int thing1, thing2; };
```

and want to make my inherited class usable with `constexpr`:

```
struct Child: public Parent
{
    constexpr Child() {}                                          //error
    constexpr Child(int t1, int t2) { thing1 = t1; thing2 = t2; } //error
    constexpr Child(const Child& c) = default;
};
```

When I compile this in Visual Studio (with /std:c++-latest), the marked ctors give an error:

```
E2433: constexpr constructor must initialized direct base class
```

It still compiles (despite reporting this as error, not warning). It also compiles fine in g++ 10 (using -std=c++2a).

(Also, I can make the error go away by explicitly calling the Parent's default ctor -- but I don't think that should be a requirement?

```
    constexpr Child() : Parent () {}
    constexpr Child(int t1, int t2) : Parent () { thing1 = t1; thing2 = t2; }
```

)

So, for the C++20 standard, who's right: VS, or g++?  Is there an approved way to give my class `constexpr` ctors, while inheriting from (or incorporating as a member variable) a base class that does not have `constexpr` ctors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Until c++20, your `Parent` class is not constexpr constructible, since there are no default initializers for the data members. I believe it's a gcc bug that allows it to compile.

You can make `Parent` constexpr constructible like this:

```
struct Parent { int thing1{}, thing2{}; };  // provide default values for members
```

Note that you can require `Parent`'s constructor to be constexpr, like this:

```
struct Parent { 
  int thing1, thing2; 
  constexpr Parent() = default;
};
```

and now gcc will fail to compile this as well.

From c++20, this restriction has been removed, by permitting default initialization for trivially default constructible types (such as `int`s) in constexpr contexts. See this [paper](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1331r2.pdf) for the rationale.

So your code should compile in c++20, but as with many such features, some compilers may not have implemented it yet.

Comment: I can't rewrite the Parent class -- it's not mine.  Is there a way to give my class constexpr ctors, while inheriting from (or incorporating as a member variable) a base class that does not have constexpr ctors?

Comment: Hmm, I don't think so. `Parent` is explicitly written to have a non-constexpr constructor, so I don't think you can change its definition after the fact. That would violate the ODR, for starters. The fix you propose in the question seems sufficient, i.e. in a constexpr constructor of `Child`, explicitly initialize `Parent`.

Comment: `clang` gives an error with `-std=c++17`, but not with `-std=c++20` [see godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/Dj2pa9).  There's probably a change in C++20 that allows implicit initialization of POD's in `constexpr` contexts.

Comment: @IlCapitano Ah, that's interesting. I'll have to look into that.

Comment: @cigien I think this is the paper: [P1331R2](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1331r2.pdf).  According to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/20) `gcc 10` and `clang 10` have both implemented this, but `MSVC` hasn't yet.

Comment: @IlCapitano Yes, that's the one. Thanks a lot, added that to the answer.

Comment: Note that by giving `Parent` a constructor of any kind, it stops being an aggregate. That may not be what you want.

Comment: I can't rewrite the Parent class.

Comment: From c++20, you don't need to rewrite `Parent`. Before c++20, you can use the workaround in your question.